# Corda : The responder flow annotation @InitiatedBy in Corda showing an incompatible types error

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

I am in the process of developing a CorDapp for a Three Party Atomic Transaction in Java.

I was trying to write 2 flows - **CreateAssetTransferRequestInitiatorFlow** (Initiator Flow) which extends an Abstract class called **AbstractCreateAssetTransferRequestFlow**(This class extends FlowLogic Class) and a corresponding responder flow called CreateAssetTransferRequestResponderFlow.

The abstract class is annotated with `@InitiatingFlow` and the responder flow when annotated with `@InitiatedBy(AbstractCreateAssetTransferRequestFlow.class)` shows an error.

The error says

> 'Found:java.lang.Class <
>   com.template.cordapp.flows.AbstractCreateAssetTransferRequestFlow>',
>   Required : 'java.lang.Class< ? extends net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic
>   < ?>>'

The abstract class extends the Flow Logic class.

Initiating Flow

[image]

Abstract Flow

[image]

Responder Flow

[image]

Can someone please help me out with this. Please find attached screenshots for your reference.

Thank you

Comment: Hey Neha, can you please remove the image links, and post the actual code in here using code tags?

Comment: I think implements part is causing the issue ;please test after removing the implements FlowlogicCommonMethod  .you can move the common method to abstract class

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `<SignedTransaction>` part from `CreateAssetTransferRequestInitiatorFlow<SignedTransction>`.

This should help you get rid of the compilation error.